# Is it possible to use the current dayname in the where clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to create a view in MySQL based on the current day of the week.  I am creating a table to keep track of tasks based on the day of the week. For example, some tasks will happen every Tuesday, some will happen on Wednesday and Friday, etc.

I decided to set the table up with a column for each day of the week. If the task needs to be executed on that day I will store a 1 in the column, otherwise it will be a 0. The table looks like this:

```
| ID | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |    Task     |
-----------------------------------
| 1  |   0    |    1    |     0     |     0    |   0    | "SomeTask"  |
| 2  |   0    |    0    |     1     |     0    |   1    | "SomeTask"  |
| 3  |   0    |    1    |     0     |     0    |   0    | "SomeTask"  |
```

I would like to create a SELECT statement that will be used in a view to show the tasks that need to be executed on the current day. In other words, today is Tuesday so I would like to a query that will get the rows with the ID of 1 and 3 to show up.

I tried the following , but it didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTasks WHERE DAYNAME(curdate()) = 1
```

Is there a better way to format the table? Is there anyway to use DAYNAME in the WHERE clause? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use `case` to build up your query, see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTasks` WHERE (CASE DAYNAME(NOW())
            WHEN 'Monday'    THEN `Monday`=1
            WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN `Tuesday`=1
            WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN `Wednesday`=1
            WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN `Thursday`=1
            WHEN 'Friday'    THEN `Friday`=1
            END)
```

Apart from that I don't see any way of you accomplishing this, as the column names are static and can't be dynamically built up based on other functions etc

Comment: omg...this is awesome!! I had the same situation but couldn't figure it out. I don't quite understand why we can't just say "where dayname(now) = 1"

why is that?

and is this the only way to dynamically set the column name we want based on date? I would like to know all ways for future reference -- THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

you can get day name of using **DAYNAME(curdate())** function
this is returning  Thursday  (today is 2015-03-05) **but**,

According to your table structure have to use 1 of following queries

01 SELECT * FROM `MyTasks` WHERE (

CASE DAYNAME(curdate())

```
        WHEN 'Monday'    THEN `Monday`=1
        WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN `Tuesday`=1
        WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN `Wednesday`=1
        WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN `Thursday`=1
        WHEN 'Friday'    THEN `Friday`=1
        END)
```

02 SELECT * FROM `MyTasks` WHERE (

CASE weekday(curdate())

```
        WHEN 0    THEN `Monday`=1
        WHEN 1    THEN `Tuesday`=1
        WHEN 2    THEN `Wednesday`=1
        WHEN 3    THEN `Thursday`=1
        WHEN 4    THEN `Friday`=1
        END)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to define a column named `Day` that would be an `enum` of each day of the week, instead of the 7 columns you have, like this :

```
`Day ENUM(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`
```

You can then just convert the current day into the adequate value (e.g. from 1 to 7) and use it in your SQL query, like this using PHP :

```
$sql = 'select * from table where Day = ' . date('N');
```

`date('N')` will return a value from 1 to 7 depending on the current day of the week.

Note : this will use the server time of the machine running PHP.

Here is an example of the table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enumtest` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Day` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7') NOT NULL,
  `Task` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: So, it seems that enum only lets you do one value. I did the columns so I could have multiple days for the same task. Is that possible with enum?

Comment: I just edited my post and provided you with an example for the table.

Comment: I think this is a great idea!! I wanted to put it in a view, but I think it would work to just get the current day with PHP and create the SQL query accordingly. The only thing that is different is that there will be duplicate data in the database from the task. Would you suggest creating a new row for the task even if it happens every day of the week?

Answer (score 0):

[DAYNAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) returns you Name of Day in a week, so your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTasks WHERE DAYNAME(NOW()) = 'Saturday';
```

I think you need [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to get  week day index.

Comment: Based on the table I listed in the initial post, and changing the day to Wednesday (today's day of the week) this doesn't return the results I am looking for. It will either return all rows if the days match or no rows if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WEEKDAY()` function to get the answer what you are looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTasks WHERE WEEKDAY(curdate()) = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the result I am looking for. The WEEKDAY function returns the numerical value of the day. My columns are labeled as names.  I think this would either return 0 rows or the full table depending if it is a Tuesday (day 1) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your model as it is and use one of two solutions: interpolate the column name on your language as you do with column values (hacky) or you can use an stored procedure for that.

But you can also do this in a RDBMS usual way, with two tables and a joint one. You would have a weekday, a task and a weekday_task table in your schema.

Table task would only have data related to the task itself, maybe with a surrogate serial id. Table weekday only data related to the weekday itself, nothing much, just information as its name and probably an working_day attribute.

And the joint would just include the task Pk and the weekday Pk. It is an ordinary n:m relation and the record would exist only for appointments.

This model is probably missing a lot of stuff related to the usual domain problem and appears to be a learning exercise, so, if it is about learning, you should go with the n:m solution.

The actual problem will probably grow to require by (valid times, start and end) for both task and weekday_task, as the weekday will probably gain a specific day companion, as a more complex solution to deal with real world frequencies anyway. This is not trivial stuff and may be GoF already mapped this for you both as persistence model and domain model.